# How to get UITableView's row and section by UIButton tag?

Tags: ios, uitableview

There is `UITableViewCell` which contain `UIButton`.

In my **cellForRowAtIndexPath**:

```
cell.toCartBtn.tag = indexPath.row;
[cell.toCartBtn addTarget:self
           action:@selector(toCart:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
```

In **toCart** method I need to get row and section by tapped button tag. How can I do it?

Comment: see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621030/how-to-know-the-indexpath-row-on-button-click-of-tableview-cell-in-a-uitableview/16621077#16621077

Comment: How about using `cell.accessoryView`?

Comment: thanks, but I have more than one section )

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See this code

```
- (void)toCart:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:buttonPosition];
    if (indexPath)
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Comment: this is still a very nice and clean way to do this. No superview or tag hacking.

Answer (score 2):

Use this simple code if UIButton is subview in cell

```
- (void)toCart:(id)sender 
{
UIButton *senderButton = (UIButton *)sender;
UITableViewCell *cell=(UITableViewCell*)senderButton.superView;
NSIndexPath *index = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom UITableViewCell subclass and handle the touch in there.

Then define a delegate for your custom table view cell and when you create the cell, assign your table view data source as the delegate.

When the cell handles the touch, send a message to the delegate and then find the index path from the table view.

```
-(void)customTableViewCellButtonPressed:(CustomTableViewCell *)cell {
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    ...
}
```

Comment: I also like the indexPathForRowAtPoint: methods others have suggested.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
- (void)toCart:(id)sender {
    CGPoint button1 = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tblName];
    NSIndexPath *index = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:button1];

    //use index variable
}
```

and also see for more details for your bug...

[Detecting which UIButton was pressed in a UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802707/detecting-which-uibutton-was-pressed-in-a-uitableview)

Answer (score 0):

For Swift

```
    let buttonPosition:CGPoint = sender.convert(CGPoint.zero, to: self.tableViewItems)
    let indexPath = self.tableViewItems.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)
    if (indexPath != nil)
    {
        print(indexPath?.section)
        print(indexPath?.row)
    }
```