# Duplicated cell when scrolling. What should I do in order to prevent it?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I'm a newbie with iOS programming language. I try to use table with button in each row.

1. when i click button in the first cell, it work pretty well.
2. but when i scroll down, the cell that i don't click also appear click.

**I want to show the clicked button in only cell(s) that I clicked?**
Code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:    (NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
ClassifyCustomCell * cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];

if ([[[arrayResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COLABO_FLD_SRNO"] isEqualToString:@"I"]) {
    cell.editButton.hidden = YES;
    cell.folder_name.text = [[arrayResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COLABO_FLD_NM"];
}else{
    cell.editButton.hidden = NO;
    cell.folder_name.text = [[arrayResult objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"COLABO_FLD_NM"];
    cell.editButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.editButton addTarget:self action:@selector(editButtonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    cell.checkButton.tag = indexPath.row;
    [cell.checkButton addTarget:self action:@selector(checkButtonActoin:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
return cell;
```

}

```
-(void)checkButtonActoin:(UIButton *)sender{
if (sender.selected == YES) {
    sender.selected = NO;
}else if(sender.selected == NO){
    sender.selected = YES;
}else {
    sender.selected = NO;
}
```

}

Comment: I think you want to manage the index and UIButton.

Comment: Yeah, something like that.

Comment: first paste your code....so we know where is actual problem is...

Comment: Can you post your code as well so we can throw more lights on it.
But i think this will help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621030/how-to-know-the-indexpath-row-on-button-click-of-tableview-cell-in-a-uitableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UITableView reuse the state of cell's subviews for new cells. To prevent reusing just configure your subviews explisitly in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. In your case you need to set `selected` property of your button to `YES`, if it was selected, and to `NO`, if it was not selected.

Add NSMutableArray property to your view controller:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arrayForSelectedIndexPaths;
```

Change your tap method:

```
-(void)checkButtonAction:(UIButton *)sender{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *) sender.superview.superview...; //find appropriate number of superviews to get your cell
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
    if (sender.selected) {
        sender.selected = NO;
        [self.arrayForSelectedIndexPaths removeObject:indexPath];
    }else {
        sender.selected = YES;
        [self.arrayForSelectedIndexPaths addObject:indexPath];
    }
}
```

Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` add this line:

```
cell.checkButton.selected = [self.arrayForSelectedIndexPaths containsObject:indexPath];
```

Comment: After apply this one, I don't have duplicated selected in each cell.

Comment: After apply this one, I don't have a duplicated selected button. But when i scroll up and down, the button that I already selected becomes unselected.

Comment: Yes. You need to provide some logic to remember cell's with selected buttons.

Comment: Ok. let me try. Thank you.

Comment: For example add an `NSMutableArray` property to your view controller,  add here indexPath for cell when button was selected and remove it when your button was unselected. Then in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` paste this cell.checkButton.selected = `[self.arrayForSelectedIndexPaths contains indexPath]`

Comment: Don't forget about finding a right number of superviews to get a cell. It could be `sender.superview.superview` or `sender.superview.superview.superview` if you button lies on other cell's subview.